# How to read some entity and change it with concurrency locking using transactions?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, concurrency, transactions

How to read some entity and change its property with concurrency locking using transactions
For example i have to do it:

`

```
// repository has access to database context
var account = _accountRepository.Get(accountId); 
if(account.Balance > product.Price){
    // Thread.Sleep(time);
    account.Balance -= product.Price;
}
_accountRepository.Update(account);
```

`

how to do so that many threads could not break it **via only transactions**? i cant use optimistic concurrency way with adding some timestamp)
if i use transactions with isolation level serializable it causes threads deadlock